# How to pass optional parameters in url, via path () function?

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I'm confused about passing optional parameter via url in Django with `path()` instead of `url()`. I found that I should use `kwargs`, so I added it to path:

```
path('all/<str:category>/<int:page_num>/', views.show_all_objects, name="show-all-objects"),
```

to

```
path('all/<str:category>/<int:page_num>/', views.show_all_objects, kwargs={'city': None}, name="show-all-objects"),
```

Ok but now how to pass additional parameter from template, I tried with:

```
<a href="{% url 'show-all-objects' category='restaurants' page_num=1 city=1 %}"
```

which returns me common error for `NoReverseMatch at /`

So I added it to url:

```
path('all/<str:category>/<int:page_num>/<int:city>/', views.show_all_objects, kwargs={'city': None}, name="show-all-objects"),
```

But error is the same, I'm pretty sure, that this is not the proper way to do it, but I cannot find info about passing optional parameter via `path()`, all info is with `url()` Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried a session variable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have got one solution/workaround.
What you need to do is, define **`N`** different path configuration in **`urls.py`**, where **`N`** is the number of ***optional parameters***

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
                  path('foo/<param_1>/<param_2>/', sample_view, name='view-with-optional-params'),
                  path('foo/<param_1>/', sample_view, name='view-with-optional-params'),
                  path('foo/', sample_view, name='view-with-optional-params'),

              ]
#views.py
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def sample_view(request, param_1=None, param_2=None):
    return HttpResponse("got response, param_1 is {} and param_2 is {}".format(param_1, param_2))

# template.html
<body>
<a href= {% url 'view-with-optional-params'  param_1='foo' param_2=123 %}>two parameters</a><br>
<a href= {% url 'view-with-optional-params'  param_1='foo' %}>one parameter</a><br>
<a href= {% url 'view-with-optional-params' %}>without parameter</a><br>
</body>
```