# How to pass optional parameters to a view in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a view that takes two optional keyword arguments: team and year_month

```
def monthly_data_list(request, year_month:str=None, team=None):
```

From the template, I want to call different combinations with either one of these 2 parameters, or both.

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) gives this example of implementing this:

```
path('monthly/list/', views.monthly_data_list, {'team':None, 'year_month'=None },name='monthly-data-list'),
```

However, calling this URL from the template with one or both arguments gives me a NoReverseMatch error:

```
hx-get="{% url 'drivers:monthly-data-list' team=None year_month=current_year_month %}"
```

I found a workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978754/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-in-url-via-path-function), which is to define paths for all combinations of parameters. This works with 2 parameters, but gets complicated on more.

How do you correctly implement multiple optional parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the documentation. If you write a path:

```
path(
    'monthly/list/',
    views.monthly_data_list,
    {'team': None, 'year_month': None},
    name='monthly-data-list',
),
```

that path will *not* take any parameters at all, optional or not. The path will accept `/monthly/list/` as path, and it will fill in `None` for `team` and `year_month`.

Passing these parameters is often done if your view can be served through *multiple* patterns, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'monthly/list/',
        views.monthly_data_list,
        {'team': None, 'year_month': None},
        name='monthly-data-list',
    ),
    path(
        'monthly/list/<str:team>/',
        views.monthly_data_list,
        {'year_month': None},
        name='monthly-data-list',
    ),
    path(
        'monthly/list/<str:team>/<str:year_month>/',
        views.monthly_data_list,
        name='monthly-data-list',
    ),
]
```

so now we have *three* patterns, one without any `team` or `year_month`, and then we use `None` instead, one with `/<str:team>/`, in which case we will fill in `None` for `year_month, and finally one where one can specify both.

In that canse we thus can make a reverse by mentioning the parameters necessary, so int his case for example:

```
{% url 'monthly-data-list' team='Foo' %}
```

this will then pick the second path, and fill in `'Foo'` for the `team`, and it will call the `monthly_data_list` with `None` for `year_month`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So this means I need to define all combinations of patterns that my templates need? The question still stands: what if I have 5 different parameters, and I want to the view to serve all possible combinations? Do I have to define 5! = 120 paths?

Comment: @Valeriu: yes, but typically you can not define all combinations, and not all combinations are useful anyway. If you would use `/foo/<str:a>/` and `/foo/<str:b>/` there is overal between the patterns, so that means if you would use these two, there is no way the path can tell which of the two it is.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!